# activatedBackgroundIndicator not working on ListView item

Tags: android, android-listview, actionmode

I know we can use `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` to make sure that the View is highlighted when "activated". I have used this on a few projects and it worked great; however, using very similar code as before, it seems not be working for me, as the Items will **not** stay highlighted when selected via `ActionMode`.

Here's the ListView item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:dividerPadding="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:minHeight="64dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/drag_handle"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:src="?attr/action_drag" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text"             
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the actual ListView layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.lazybits.sidekick"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:collapsed_height="2dp"
    app:drag_enabled="true"
    app:drag_handle_id="@id/drag_handle"
    app:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
    app:drag_start_mode="onDown"
    app:float_alpha="0.6"
    app:float_background_color="?attr/bg_drag_item"
    app:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"        
    app:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
    app:use_default_controller="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/no_tasks" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note I did try with and without `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` and that made no difference.

ActionMode picks up the fact that the items are being selected, as I have a Log event tell me so, and I set the title of the ActionMode to show the amount of items selected; however, the items will not remain "highlighted" even though they are "activated".

Here's a quick [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0d2nse8c9cq3ki/Screenshot_2013-03-17-06-46-56.png) of the ActionMode working, but items not being highlighted.

Comment: As a simple test, did you tried using a simple `ListView` instead of `DragSortListView`? If it works with a simple `ListView` then you know who to ask to solve the problem:) (also, please don't prefix the question's title with *Android* as it just adds noise, the tag at the bottom is more then enough)